# convert php mcrypt_encrypt MCRYPT_3DES to Java

Tags: java, php, encryption, cryptography, 3des

I have code in PHP

```
$res = strtoupper(bin2hex(mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_3DES, $this->hex2str($key), $this->hex2str($data), MCRYPT_MODE_ECB)));

public function hex2str($data) { 
      $len = strlen($data); 
      $res = pack("H" . $len, $data);
      return $res; 
}
```

I try to create in java version. 
Java code :

```
private String doEncrypt3DES(String key, String data) throws Exception{
        SecretKey secretKey;
        byte[] keyValue;
        Cipher c;

        keyValue = Hex.decodeHex(key.toCharArray());
        DESedeKeySpec keySpec = new DESedeKeySpec(keyValue);
        secretKey = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("DESede").generateSecret(keySpec);

        // Create the cipher
        c = Cipher.getInstance("DESede/ECB/NoPadding");

        c.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKey);
        byte[] text = data.getBytes("utf-8"); // Base64.decodeBase64(data);
        byte[] textEncrypt = c.doFinal(text);
        String hex = bytesToHex(textEncrypt);
        return hex;
}
```

But they got different result. Can you help me to fix java code? 
**data** : `CED0CF172E8AC451B39FC746C5339F29`

**key** : `436C6561724B657944657632536E724D436C6561724B6579`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use hex decode and not utf-8 decode to data.

Comment: Correct. Note that you could add 0 to 7 bytes valued `00` to the right of the plaintext in your Java code to match the "zero padding" of PHP. Note that that zero padding is not safe for binary that ends with zero's. Also note that ECB is not safe, nor is CBC if it is used on its own within a transport protocol.

Comment: @owlstead can you suggest the best mode if ECB and CBC are not safe? In your comment, so I need to add 00 to the result. ex result : 27B5E41CA14260119ABF36D9D18FFBF8, and it must be 27B5E41CA14260119ABF36D9D18FFBF800 ?

Comment: 1) GCM would be safe, or you could use a HMAC over the ciphertext and IV using CBC. 2) No, that one is already 16 bytes and thus dividable by 16. Note that to use binary you should use PKCS#7 compatible padding.

Comment: You're welcome, note it should be dividable by 8. AES uses a safer block size than 3DES, 16 bytes, so I got stuck on that one :)